# HP Elitebook 8560w Sluggish

Tags: laptop, hp-elitebook

At work I'm using an HP EliteBook 8560w laptop. Now this is a reasonably nice laptop, so I didn't expect any slowdowns from it.

Indeed, compile times are fast, and it can run almost anything satisfactorily, but it's slow when opening new applications. On Windows, the music will cut out if I'm running VisualStudio as well.

It feels like it's maybe the hard-drive that's problematic, is there any way to confirm this?

Has anyone else experienced this problem with this laptop?